# Android xml file layout gets messed up when loaded on emulator leaving blank space on the left

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming, I have created this xml file: lockerbookpage.xml that contains many buttons, however, the error occurs when I load the app onto the emulator, the buttons gets messed up pretty bad
There seems to be this blank white space on the left side of the screen:

here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/smallButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/sis" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/soeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:text="@string/soe" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/solButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/soeButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/soeButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/sol" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewNumLockersAvailable"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/sob" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/allSchoolsButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sobButton"
     android:text="@string/all" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/smallButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/allSchoolsButton"
    android:text="@string/small" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mediumButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lv1button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:text="@string/med" />    

<Button
    android:id="@+id/largeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lv1button"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/allSizesButton"
    android:text="@string/large" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/allSizesButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lv1button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/all" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/lv1button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/smallButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/smallButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="@string/lv1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/lv2button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lv1button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lv1button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mediumButton"
    android:text="@string/lv2" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/lv3button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textViewNumLockersAvailable"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/largeButton"
    android:text="@string/lv3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/allLevelsButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lv3button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lv3button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/all" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/soeButton"
    android:text="@string/search" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textViewNumLockersAvailable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lv1button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/ViewNumLockersAvailable" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/unselectAll"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="returnToMain"
    android:text="@string/logout" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/unselectAll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/searchButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/searchButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewNumLockersAvailable"
    android:text="@string/unselectAll" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used `+id` for the alignment +id is used for creating an id try it out with `id` instead.

I hope it works

Comment: It doesn't matter unless there are typos in identifier names.